# Mvn build success but no tests are executed

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, cobertura

I have almost no idea why this could be happening but when I run

```
mvn clean install
```

or

```
#Builds with class instrumentation (code coverage)
mvn cobertura:cobertura
```

Everything was working just fine until I made a slight change which was to my pom.xml file, so it could contain dependencies classes I was using in my code rather than literally importing several classes into my project.

This is the terminal/console out I get when I run maven:

```
SDGL12025ba66:TestCompletenessCompilerRuntime mosawi$ mvn cobertura:cobertura
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building TestCompletenessCompilerRuntime 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> cobertura-maven-plugin:2.7:cobertura (default-cli) > [cobertura]test @ TestCompletenessCompilerRuntime >>>
Downloading: http://ctg-cache-repo.corp.generalatomics.net/nexus/content/repositories/public/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.6.2/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.2.pom
Downloaded: http://ctg-cache-repo.corp.generalatomics.net/nexus/content/repositories/public/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.6.2/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.2.pom (2 KB at 14.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://ctg-cache-repo.corp.generalatomics.net/nexus/content/groups/public/com/generalatomics/ctg/tla/models/model-data-source/2015.1.11-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://ctg-cache-repo.corp.generalatomics.net/nexus/content/groups/public/com/generalatomics/ctg/tla/models/model-data-source/2015.1.11-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (804 B at 3.1 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://ctg-cache-repo.corp.generalatomics.net/nexus/content/groups/public/com/generalatomics/ctg/tla/compilers/decision-map-common/2015.1.11-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://ctg-cache-repo.corp.generalatomics.net/nexus/content/groups/public/com/generalatomics/ctg/tla/compilers/decision-map-common/2015.1.11-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (809 B at 3.6 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://ctg-cache-repo.corp.generalatomics.net/nexus/content/groups/public/com/generalatomics/ctg/tla/models/decision-table-model/2015.1.11-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://ctg-cache-repo.corp.generalatomics.net/nexus/content/groups/public/com/generalatomics/ctg/tla/models/decision-table-model/2015.1.11-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (807 B at 1.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://ctg-cache-repo.corp.generalatomics.net/nexus/content/groups/public/com/generalatomics/ctg/tla/compilers/mapping-maven-plugin/2015.1.11-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://ctg-cache-repo.corp.generalatomics.net/nexus/content/groups/public/com/generalatomics/ctg/tla/compilers/mapping-maven-plugin/2015.1.11-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (810 B at 3.7 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://ctg-cache-repo.corp.generalatomics.net/nexus/content/groups/public/com/generalatomics/ctg/tla/models/calc-graph-model/2015.1.11-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://ctg-cache-repo.corp.generalatomics.net/nexus/content/groups/public/com/generalatomics/ctg/tla/models/calc-graph-model/2015.1.11-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (803 B at 2.1 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://ctg-cache-repo.corp.generalatomics.net/nexus/content/repositories/public/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.6.2/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.2.jar
Downloaded: http://ctg-cache-repo.corp.generalatomics.net/nexus/content/repositories/public/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.6.2/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.2.jar (10 KB at 380.9 KB/sec)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ TestCompletenessCompilerRuntime ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) @ TestCompletenessCompilerRuntime ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- cobertura-maven-plugin:2.7:instrument (default-cli) @ TestCompletenessCompilerRuntime ---
[INFO] Cobertura 2.1.1 - GNU GPL License (NO WARRANTY) - See COPYRIGHT file
[INFO] Cobertura: Loaded information on 13 classes.
[INFO] Cobertura: Saved information on 13 classes.
[INFO] Cobertura: Saved information on 13 classes.

[ERROR] SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/mosawi/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.0.13/logback-classic-1.0.13.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/mosawi/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.6.2/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]

[INFO] Instrumentation was successful.
[INFO] NOT adding cobertura ser file to attached artifacts list.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ TestCompletenessCompilerRuntime ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 832 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ TestCompletenessCompilerRuntime ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 7 source files to /Users/mosawi/Perforce/mosawi_newTPS/QE/automation/TestCompletenessCompilerRuntime/target/test-classes
[INFO] /Users/mosawi/Perforce/mosawi_newTPS/QE/automation/TestCompletenessCompilerRuntime/src/test/java/com/generalatomics/ctg/tla/compilers/CompilerTest.java: /Users/mosawi/Perforce/mosawi_newTPS/QE/automation/TestCompletenessCompilerRuntime/src/test/java/com/generalatomics/ctg/tla/compilers/CompilerTest.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
[INFO] /Users/mosawi/Perforce/mosawi_newTPS/QE/automation/TestCompletenessCompilerRuntime/src/test/java/com/generalatomics/ctg/tla/compilers/CompilerTest.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ TestCompletenessCompilerRuntime ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /Users/mosawi/Perforce/mosawi_newTPS/QE/automation/TestCompletenessCompilerRuntime/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configurator@7c40bc88
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.32 sec

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< cobertura-maven-plugin:2.7:cobertura (default-cli) < [cobertura]test @ TestCompletenessCompilerRuntime <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- cobertura-maven-plugin:2.7:cobertura (default-cli) @ TestCompletenessCompilerRuntime ---
[INFO] Cobertura 2.1.1 - GNU GPL License (NO WARRANTY) - See COPYRIGHT file
[INFO] Cobertura: Loaded information on 13 classes.
Report time: 249ms

[INFO] Cobertura Report generation was successful.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.421 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-08-05T14:06:28-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 28M/438M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
SDGL12025ba66:TestCompletenessCompilerRuntime mosawi$
```

I really don't understand what could be causing this? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

That error you see for slf4j should be fine. I've seen that before, so I am certain thats not the culprit of what is happening here

**Edit:**
I'm noticing that my test seem to be executing with TestNG but I'm using JUnit:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configurator@7c40bc88
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.32 sec
```

Why would mvn clean install try to build or run my tests with TestNG rather than Junit? Could it be the new dependencies I added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surefire has a mechanism to figure out whether to run JUnit or TestNG. Probably something in your dependencies/code is making surefire try to use TestNG.

You can disable the automatic detection and force a test provider (see the [selecting providers](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/providers.html) in the documentation). Just for future reference, you need to configure surefire in the following way (taken from the previous link). This will force Surefire to use a Junit 4.7 compatible provider.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.1</version>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
        <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.1</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </plugin>
```

I've seen this issue once before, about 6-7 years ago, and I cannot remember what I did to fix it to make Surefire detect the test provider properly, but I do remember debbuging the surefire plugin.

Comment: Thank you, this worked! And yes, you are right, it was a dependency which caused it to use TestNG

Comment: How could I specify to use TestNG instead of Junit?

Comment: @mosawi read the link I posted above, they are highlighted there :).

Comment: @Augusto God bless your memory, thanks !!

Answer (score 3):

Just to point. Make sure your test classes are in a test folder(package), and class name should be Test*, *Test, *TestCase.

Comment: Yes, they are properly organized into src/test/java and have proper @Test annotations via JUnit. Everything was working properly until I made a change in my pom and deleted some classes I wasn't using.